# Аннотация Value в Spring не внедряет проперти

Tags: java, spring, properties

Есть два класса

PersistenceConfig:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class PersistenceConfig {
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
private String password;

@Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
private String driverClassName;

@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String url;

@Bean
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    return dataSource;
}
//...
```

MailConfig:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class MailConfig {
@Value("${spring.mail.host}")
private String host;

@Value("${spring.mail.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${spring.mail.password}")
private String password;

@Value("${spring.mail.port}")
private int port;

@Value("${spring.mail.protocol}")
private String protocol;

@Value("${mail.debug}")
private String debug;

@Bean
public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSenderImpl = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

    mailSenderImpl.setHost(host);
    mailSenderImpl.setPort(port);
    mailSenderImpl.setUsername(username);
    mailSenderImpl.setPassword(password);

    Properties properties = mailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties();

    properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", protocol);
    properties.setProperty("mail.debug", debug);

    return mailSenderImpl;
}
```

А проблема в том, что в MailConfig параметры спокойно цепляются из файла application.properties, а в PersistenceConfig все переменные инициализируются все равно null'ами, хотя среда разработки вроде как видит эти параметры. Может сталкивался кто с таким.

Comment: В общем забавная штука.
Если ставить Autowired private DataSource dataSource; после Value полей, то они инициализируются, но не переменными из пропертей, а этими вот самыми строчками с долларом. Почему? А вот потому что у меня там ниже есть бин еще один
Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
И если его убрать, то переменные инициализируются верно.

Comment: Почему это так работает и как зависят бины, находящиеся в конфиг классе на поведение value полей, я что-то не очень понимаю.

Answer (score 1):

В общем забавная штука. Если ставить

```
@Autowired private DataSource dataSource;
```

после Value полей, то они инициализируются, но не переменными из пропертей, а этими вот самыми строчками с долларом. Ну то есть скажем поле

```
@Value("${spring.mail.host}")
private String host;
```

инициализируется строкой "${spring.mail.host}", а не тем, что лежит в проперти по этой ссылке.
Почему? А вот оказывается некоторые бины влияют на это. У меня в этом же классе лежал бин

```
@Bean 
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor() { 
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor(); 
}
```

И если его убрать в другой класс, то переменные инициализируются верно. Логического объяснения этому у меня пока нет. Наверняка где-то в документации это описано.